# How do I deploy a GKE Workload with my Docker image from the Artifact Registry using Terraform?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a kubernetes cluster that I have stood up with terraform in GCP. Now I want to deploy/run my Docker image to/on it, from the GCP console I would do this by going to the *workloads* section of the *kubernetes engine* portion of the console and then selecting *Deploy a containerized application*, I however want to do this with terraform, and am having difficulty determining how to do this and finding good reference examples for how to do it. Any examples on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: you can check examples from this [terraform-google-modules](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

- For managing workloads on Kubernetes, you can use this [Kubectl Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gavinbunney/kubectl/latest/docs)
- For custom images that preset in a 3rd party registry, you'll need to create a Kubernetes secret of type `Docker` and then use it in your manifests via `imagePullSecrets` attribute. Check out this [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).